# Using check_by_ssh in Nagios Yielding Strange Behavior (and Remote Execution Failure)

Tags: ssh, nagios, remote-execution

I'm new to Nagios, and I've been trying to get Nagios to handle a few simple check_by_ssh commands. I'm at the point where I'm successfully able to run the command from the command line like so:

```
#/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_by_ssh -H HERP.DERP.COM -C "/home/derrp/bin/...
 check_disk -w 50 -c 10 -A"
```

Which presents

```
DISK OK - free space: blah blah blah
```

So, that's good; it works o.k. from the command line. However, when I throw that into my commands.cfg file (using macros `$USER1$` and `$HOSTADDRESS$` at first, though the literal information yields the same results), and check Nagios' web interface to verify, it tells me

```
Remote command execution failed: ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): 
No such file or directory
```

I've ensured ssh-askpass is installed. What gives?

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, adding the "-E" flag fixed it. According to the `check_by_ssh` man page, this is the ignore `STDERR` flag. Now I get the output from check_raid.

Final command:

> $USER1$/check_by_ssh -i ~nagios/.ssh/id_dsa -H $HOSTADDRESS$
>   -t 60 -l -l root  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=15 -o BatchMode=yes -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -C
>   "/usr/local/libexec/nagios/check_raid" -E

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up ssh keys so that the 'nagios' user can ssh to the remote host(s) **without a passphrase on the private key**, or it cannot run checks using check_by_ssh.

Until you can run (*as the nagios user*) something like this...

```
ssh [nagios@]remotehost.example.com /path/to/your/plugins/check_procs
```

... you do not have keys set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - running

```
sudo -u nagios check_by_ssh ....
```

helped - I had wrong permissions on the private key. But sudo was essential here - what works ran as root, doesn't necessarily work as nagios.